# Change Background Color of One Tile on Promoted Links Page in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to change the background color of ONE tile on the promoted links page in SharePoint.
I saw this post using CSS:

```
<style type='text/css'>
  div.ms-tileview-tile-content {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

This changed all of the tiles to red.  I want to select a specific tile and determine the color.  All of the tiles are currently navy blue and I want to change one of them to light blue.

Comment: maybe `div.ms-tileview-tile-root:first-child {background-color:red;}`?

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery, or are you stuck with only CSS?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the background image area for the tile gets it's `alt` attribute set as the link item's title.  So you can use the following to target a single specific tile:

`.ms-promlink-body img[alt*="text from the title"] { background-color: red; }`

where "text from the title" is some text that will uniquely identify the target tile based on it's title.

Comment: +1 as its the best answer for this use-case. See [CSS n-th child selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) for other use-cases

Answer (score 1):

If you use :first: or eq(2) etc. and reorder the tile list, the colors will not follow suit. Another option is to identify the webpart ID and actual tile ID (using dev tools) on a page, and then use the following:

```
#Tile_WPQ3_4_2, #Tile_WPQ3_5_2, #Tile_WPQ3_6_2 {background-color: rgb(135, 178, 19);}
#Tile_WPQ2_12_2 {background-color: rgb(254, 191, 0);}
#Tile_WPQ2_15_2 {background-color: #006600;}
```

Line 1 - first 3 are set to all the same color, Line 2 & 3 - different colors.
Tile is the list name, WPQ3 & WPQ2 is the webpart, _12 is the tile ID and _2 is the layer on the tile where the div/block background color is set.

This method is applied to the page the tiles are displayed on, not site-wide, and if you add more webparts to the page, you may need to tweak the WPQ #.